# How to input number of testcases in C++?

Tags: c++, input

While working with questions on hackerrank, I found questions which required to input number of test cases. Please guide me on how do I take the input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m;
    int n;
    cin>>n>>m;
    
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    
    int maxim=INT_MIN;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
        {
            sum+=arr[j];
            int sums=sum%m;
            maxim=max(sums,maxim);
        }
    }
    cout<<maxim;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code print the maximum modulus of the sum of a subarray for a given array.
How do I input number of test cases so my input looks like this :
2
3 2 
1 2 3
3 5
1 5 9

Comment: Please note: VLA (Variable Length Arrays), so ````arr[n]```` are not part of the C++ language. If you use a compiler and set the language to C++, this will not compile. If you want to learn C++, then you must not use VLA. And, if, and only if, you want to learn C++, then stay away from such sides like Hackerrank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a while loop

```
int testcase;
cin >> testcase;
while(testcase--)
```

or using a for loop

```
int testcase;
cin >> testcase;
for(int i = 0; i < testcase; i++)
```

The entire code would look like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        int m;
        int n;
        cin>>n>>m;
        
        int arr[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i];
        }
        
        int maxim=INT_MIN;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            int sum=0;
            for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
            {
                sum+=arr[j];
                int sums=sum%m;
                maxim=max(sums,maxim);
            }
        }
        cout << maxim << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For the given test case as the number of test case = 2, The code written inside the while loop will run 2 times.

As there are multiple test cases you will need to modify how you print the output based on the output format mentioned in the question

```
cout << maxim << '\n';
```

or

```
cout << maxim << " ";
```

Comment: `int arr[n];` VLA is compiler dependent. Using `std::vector` is better